# what is the use of _merge_before and _merge_after event in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, event-observer, price

I want to know the difference between following Magento 2 events

```
  1)sales_quote_add_item

  2)_merge_before

  3) _merge_after
```

and how I can use the event in *event.xml*

**sales_quote_add_item** and **_merge_before** is both are same event or different

could anyone give some ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Both are different events.

**sales_quote_add_item**

*When item added to the cart this event triggered.*

**_merge_before**

*Event is triggered when quotes are merged. Example When guest user login if he had an item in the cart then both quotes are merged.*

Comment: _merge_before this event not working for me....

Comment: **sales_quote_merge_before** complete event name.

Comment: can i use both in same time ....

Comment: sales_quote_merge_before 

$item = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
        $product =  $item->getProduct();  //null on product item....

Comment: @prabhakaran7 try $item = $observer->getEvent()->getSource()->getQuoteItem();

Comment: $item = $observer->getEvent()->getSource()->getQuoteItem() ; // i'm getting null in $item...

Comment: do you know which event I can use  to change price while merging a product (quote item)  with cart

Comment: @prabhakaran7 sales_quote_add_item this event

Comment: sales_quote_add_item  i tried this event but setting wrong custom price  only fro merging to cart...